# Reattach entity with relations to reset entity manager

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using the default entity manager and retrieve a list of entities with `createQuery()->getResult()`.
I iterate over them and when executing some stuff there could be an exception. I catch the exception and reset the manager.

```
$this->registry->resetManager();
$em = $this->registry->getManager();
```

In general it works like expected, but it seems that the entities with the resetted entity manager makes some problems when I try to use them in a query.

I have already tried to reattach them to the new entity manager with `merge`, which works in general, but all relations find new entities. Cascade merge doesn't work either, same problem.

Is there a simple method to reattach an entity including all relations?